# In C++, can I typedef an element type from pointer type?

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef

The title says it, look at my minimal example:

```
template<class ptr_to_t>
void f(ptr_to_t x) {
    typedef ptr_to_t t; // does not compile
    t elem = *x;
}

int main()
{
    int five = 5;
    f<int*>(&five);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled like this:

```
g++ -Wall typedef.cpp -o typedef
```

This does not compile. What I want is to change the marked line (line 3) such that `t` is of type `int` (in this instantiation).

1. Is such a typedef possible in C++11?
2. Is such a typedef possible in "old" C++?

Note: I guess this is a duplicate, but I really could not find this question anywhere.

Comment: "In C++ or C++11" - so I guess C++11 is not C++?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You should use [`std::remove_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer) from `type_traits` header:

```
typedef typename std::remove_pointer<ptr_to_t>::type t;
```

In pre-C++11 you could write your own implementation(like in the link above, for example):

```
template< class T > struct remove_pointer                    {typedef T type;};
template< class T > struct remove_pointer<T*>                {typedef T type;};
template< class T > struct remove_pointer<T* const>          {typedef T type;};
template< class T > struct remove_pointer<T* volatile>       {typedef T type;};
template< class T > struct remove_pointer<T* const volatile> {typedef T type;};
```

Comment: This answers my question completely, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You should use C++11 [std::remove_pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class ptr_to_t>
void f(ptr_to_t x) {
    typedef ptr_to_t t; // does not compile
    typename std::remove_pointer<t>::type elem = *x;
}

int main()
{
    int five = 5;
    f<int*>(&five);
    return 0;
}
```

(Compiled in [IdeOne](http://ideone.com/FpQ9Ja))

If targeting C++03, you can to use [boost::remove_pointer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/remove_pointer.html) instead or provide your own implementation (courtesy of competing soon's answer, [compiled in IdeOne](http://ideone.com/qnzgUS)):

```
template< class T > struct remove_pointer                    {typedef T type;};
template< class T > struct remove_pointer<T*>                {typedef T type;};
template< class T > struct remove_pointer<T* const>          {typedef T type;};
template< class T > struct remove_pointer<T* volatile>       {typedef T type;};
template< class T > struct remove_pointer<T* const volatile> {typedef T type;};
```